# What did the meraglim that Moshe sent eat?

Tags: parashat-shelach, meraglim-spies, mon-manna

What did the scouts that Moshe sent eat?

- Did manna fall for them in Eretz Yisrael (the land of Israel)?
- Did they take manna from outside with them and it didn't go bad, as when everyone went in 38.5 years later?  I'm extrapolating from the future because it's the only other intersection between manna and Eretz Yisrael.
- Did they buy food?
- Some other possibility I haven't thought of?

Any of these options are plausible to me.  I'm looking for sources.

Comment: Well they brought back fruit,so I would assume they ate it too

Comment: @sam So they had their fruit and ate it too? That doesn't seem right. :P